# Facebook C# SDK LoginButton state management

Tags: facebook-c#-sdk

I have implemented the Facebook C# SDK Client LoginButton in my Windows 8 app and have it working fine in a mode similar to the provided sample app.  My issue is that in anything beyond a sort of "Hello World" sample app, the login button needs to be able to synchronize its state in order to be useful.

The most obvious issue is that when navigating away from the page with the login button, then later navigating back to that page, the login button has no state at all (it has no session, no user, doesn't know you're actually logged in, etc).  A somewhat more subtle version of this problem is that in a real app you typically don't want to force the user to authenticate to Facebook unless it is required (so if you have a valid token from a previous session of your app, the user is considered logged in and you don't go prompting them to log in again when your app starts).  But since there is no way to communicate any state to the login button control, and the control doesn't seem to serialize/manage its own state, you can't do any of this.

I'm new to Windows 8 programming, so maybe I'm missing some magic connection that would make this work (I see the events that indicate when the state changes and the classes that serialize the state, but I don't see any way to get that state into the LoginButton, or to otherwise direct the login button to serialize its state).  And the LoginButton class is nailed down to the point that there doesn't seem to be a way to hammer the state in - everything related to the session state is read-only/private.

The fact that the login button (and the rest of the controls) are not used in the only non-trivial SDK example (Scrumptious) does not really inspire confidence in the real-world readiness of these controls.

Answer (score 6):

OK, looks like I'm going to answer my own question ;)

The LoginButton uses the FacebookSessionClient internally to login/logout, and the FacebookSessionClient does in fact serialize session state using the appropriate FacebookSessionCacheProvider.  So far, so good.

The trick then is to set any existing session state into the button when the page is loaded.  I was originally convinced that this was not possible, as LoginButton properties for the CurrentSession and CurrentUser were read-only.  But after further review, I found that I can actually set these values via their dependency properties using SetValue.

I track the session and user state from the LoginButton using the appropriate event handlers, as follows:

```
    private void OnSessionStateChanged(object sender, Facebook.Client.Controls.SessionStateChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.SessionState == Facebook.Client.Controls.FacebookSessionState.Opened)
        {
            App.CurrentSession = this.loginButton.CurrentSession;
        }
        else if (e.SessionState == Facebook.Client.Controls.FacebookSessionState.Closed)
        {
            App.CurrentSession = null;

            // The control signals when user info is set (handled in OnUserInfoChanged below), but not when it
            // is cleared (probably a bug), so we clear our reference here when the session ends.
            //
            App.CurrentUser = null;
        }
    }

    private void OnUserInfoChanged(object sender, UserInfoChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        App.CurrentUser = this.loginButton.CurrentUser;
    }
```

On page load, I get the session state from the cache (so this works when launching the app, when resuming the app, and when navigating back to this page from another page) and I restore the LoginButton state as appropriate using SetValue.  I have some added logic to automatically re-auth if the user was previously logged in, but has an expired token (happens often on launch due to use of short-lived tokens).  I also have logic to reload the CurrentUser when needed.  The result of this is that the login button has the correct state in all three cases.

```
    private async void navigationHelper_LoadState(object sender, LoadStateEventArgs e)
    {
        this.loginButton.ApplicationId = Constants.FacebookAppId;

        App.CurrentSession = FacebookSessionCacheProvider.Current.GetSessionData();
        if ((App.CurrentSession != null) && (App.CurrentSession.Expires <= DateTime.UtcNow))
        {
            // User was previously logged in, but session expired.  Log them in again...
            App.CurrentSession = await App.FacebookSessionClient.LoginAsync(Constants.FacebookPermissions);
        }

        if (App.CurrentSession != null)
        {
            this.loginButton.SetValue(LoginButton.CurrentSessionProperty, App.CurrentSession);
            if (App.CurrentUser == null)
            {
                FacebookClient client = new FacebookClient(App.CurrentSession.AccessToken);
                dynamic result = await client.GetTaskAsync("me");
                App.CurrentUser = new GraphUser(result);
            }
        }

        if (App.CurrentUser != null)
        {
            this.loginButton.SetValue(LoginButton.CurrentUserProperty, App.CurrentUser);
        }
    }
```

I think the right solution would be for the LoginButton to get the session state using the cache provider and initialize itself appropriately (at least in the case that the session is valid/unexpired) so it would just work "magically" without any of these gymnastics.

Comment: After having evolved my app (and my Windows 8 skills) somewhat, I am now using an MVVM architecture, as seems to be the recommended approach (by Microsoft and others).  Now that I am in this mode, I no longer like the code-behind solution posted as the answer here.  It works fine, but a *MUCH* more elegant solution would be for the LoginButton to expose the CurrentSession and CurrentUser in such a way that I could bind them to my ViewModel (using TwoWay binding, so the ViewModel could initialize them and be automatically updated when they change via user interaction with the LoginButton).